# Asterisk - can't dial if hints are used

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

I'm trying to learn Asterisk by following the [Definitive Guide](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/index.html). I'm trying to achieve the following:

**Extensions**

- 7001
- 7002
- 7003

..each with hints so my IP phone handsets can show busy lights.

I seem to be able to calling to work OK, but as soon as I try to get hints working, I can no longer call (so it's calling or hints working, not both!). When I try to call, I get this message:

> [Oct 14 15:25:51] NOTICE[3262][C-0000000a]: chan_sip.c:25545 handle_request_invite: Call from '7001' (192.168.8.129:5160) to extension '7002' rejected because extension not found in context 'LocalSets'.

**Further debugging info**

> ubuntupbx*CLI> dialplan show 7003@LocalSets
>   [ Context 'LocalSets' created by 'pbx_config' ]
>     '7003' =>         hint: SIP/7003                                [pbx_config]
>
> -= 1 extension (1 priority) in 1 context. =-
>
> ubuntupbx*CLI> dialplan show 7002@LocalSets
>   [ Context 'LocalSets' created by 'pbx_config' ]
>     '7002' =>         hint: SIP/7002                                [pbx_config]
>
> -= 1 extension (1 priority) in 1 context. =-

My config looks as follows:

**sip.conf**

```
[general]
localnet=192.168.8.0/255.255.255.0
context=unauthenticated
allowguest=no
srvlookup=yes
callcounter=yes
limitonpeers=yes

[office-phone](!)
type=friend
context=LocalSets
busylevel=1
host=dynamic
dtmfmode=auto
subscribecontext=LocalSets
allowsubscribe=yes
disallow=all
allow=g722
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw


[7001](office-phone)
secret=123

[7002](office-phone)
secret=456

[7003](office-phone)
secret=789
```

**extensions.conf**

```
[LocalSets]
exten => 7001,hint,SIP/7001
exten => 7002,hint,SIP/7002
exten => 7003,hint,SIP/7003

exten => 200,1,Answer()
        same => n,Playback(hello-world)
        same => n,Hangup()

exten => 600,1,Answer()
        same => n,ConfBridge(1234)
```

If I remove the "hint" wording and replace it with "1", calling works, but hints don't.

I've tried running with debugging on, but only see the same message, with additional info (IP addresses etc). I'm sure it's a schoolboy error, but I can't crack it. Can anyone help?

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 Server LTS, running *Asterisk 13.1.0~dfsg-1.1ubuntu4* installed via apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint context must be a separate context, that's the main reason you are getting either hints or `Dial` and not both. So aside from having a regular extension context for voice calls, you should create a separate hint context, and it's the latter one that you should mention in the `subscribecontext`.

Like

```
[local-ext]
exten => _7XXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})

[hints]
exten => _X.,hint,Custom:DND${EXTEN}&SIP/${EXTEN}
```

or whatever.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that makes sense. So to clarify, your advice is to create a new context (e.g. "[phonepresence]") with the hint rules in, and then change the subscribecontext for my template in sip.conf to say "phonepresence"?

Comment: Exactly. I've edit my answer to be more ... I don't know ... rich on examples.

Comment: Thanks, I've copied your config in. I can now dial successfully, but hints aren't working as expected yet, but that's given me a start, thanks. I'm using a Draytek 350 IP phone which is a little old now, so I suspect I may need to do something specifically to make the block lights work on there. X-Lite is working as it should do for the presence, so something else afoot!

Comment: That's an example from a working * using *Custom* state. A brief explanation of this concept can be found here: http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/usingCustomDeviceStates.html . You can, however, adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working with  **exten => _X.,hint,Custom:DND${EXTEN}&SIP/${EXTEN}**  and the following in my sip.conf  
limitonpeers=yes
notifyringing=yes
notifyhold=yes
notifycid=yes